# Am I able to use dynamic parameters in libraries configuration files?

Tags: 8

I have hard coded GMaps API key in URL inside in the libraries.yml file.

Would I be able to use a dynamic parameter for this key?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use [`hook_library_info_build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_library_info_build/8.2.x). It's a new (to D8) hook that allows you to define libraries at runtime.

[Here's the change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2402315) that talks about it's introduction. It's unlikely to go anywhere, but here's the description from the change record:

> There was no way to dynamically register libraries. Using hook_library_info_alter() to register new library is possible but doesn't end well in alter/weight.
>
> Therefore a new hook is created namely hook_library_info_build()

Alternatively; you could potentially add the hook as normal in your `example.libraries.yml` file, and then use [`hook_library_info_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_library_info_alter/8.2.x).